# Deserialize JSON object with variable strings

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON response in c# using Newtonsoft.Json

Here is an example of the type of JSON response I'm working with:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "fixes": [
    {
      "fix1": "this is fix 1",
      "fix2": "this is fix 2",
      "fix3": "this is fix 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this response there can be any number of "fixes."

My object class looks like this:

```
public class Update
{
    public class Fix
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Root
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public List<Fix> fixes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here I'm deserializing the http response and trying to get value of fixes, but all of the values are null:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Update.Root>(strContent);
        
Update.Fix fixes = root.fixes[0];

foreach (var fix in fixes.Values)
{
    string test = fix.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Eliminate the class `Fix`.  In `Root` have `public List<Dictionary<string, string>> fixes { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the class `Fix`.  In `Root` have `public List<Dictionary<string, string>> fixes { get; set; }`:

```
public class Root
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> fixes { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to loop through all the keys and values, you can use [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) to project the list of dictionaries to an enumerable of key/value pairs:

```
foreach (var pair in root.fixes.SelectMany(p => p))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PlYEXQ).

Answer (score 0):

your fixes are a dictionary, not a collection, but you can convert it to a collecton

```
         List<string> fixes = JObject.Parse(json)["fixes"]
        .SelectMany(jo => ((JObject)jo).Properties()
        .Select(p => (string) p.Value))
        .ToList();
        
        foreach (string fix in fixes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fix);
        }
```

output

```
this is fix 1
this is fix 2
this is fix 3
```

or dictionary

```
     Dictionary<string, string> fixes = JObject.Parse(json)["fixes"]
    .Select(jo => jo.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>())
    .FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (var fix in fixes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fix.Key + " : " + fix.Value);
    }
```

output

```
fix1 : this is fix 1
fix2 : this is fix 2
fix3 : this is fix 3
```